# Infinitely listen to jabber events?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby

I am writing a chat application, using Jabber, on Ruby on Rails. Sending messages was quite easy to implement, but receiving messages in a loop is quite a challenge.

I want to get callbacks from the server without browser refreshes. I tried to use ActionController::Live for this.

In my client side, my code is:

```
var source = new EventSource('/chat/events');
source.addEventListener('refresh', function(event)
{
AddMessage(event.data);
});
```

My controller code is:

```
def chat_events
  # SSE expects the `text/event-stream` content type
  response.headers['Content-Type'] = 'text/event-stream'
  sse = Reloader::SSE.new(response.stream)

puts "Starting XMMP call"
 begin
  @xmmpClient = XmppClient.new
  @xmmpClient.loginUsingNameAndPassword(****, ***)
  @xmmpClient.listen_connections sse
 rescue IOError
  puts "Error"
  # When the client disconnects, we'll get an IOError on write
 ensure
  puts "closing stream"
  sse.close
 end
end
```

And, my XMMP client is:

```
def listen_connections(writer = nil)
 if not @logged_in
    puts "Not logged"
    raise "Not logged"
 end
 @robot.send(Jabber::Presence.new.set_show(nil))
 loop do
  puts "Listening callback"
  @robot.add_message_callback do |message|
    puts "Got message " + message.inspect
    if not writer.nil?
      writer.write({ :message => message.body }, :event => 'refresh')
    end
  end
  sleep 2
end
end
```

What I got:

1. The `chat_events` method of the controller is called every second or so.
2. Because of this, several callbacks are executed at once.
3. When I got a message, I got it four or five times.

   ```
   {"message":"fffdsfd"}
   {"message":"fffdsfd"}
   {"message":"fffdsfd"}
   {"message":"fffdsfd"}
   ```
4. And the worst stuff - my server is not responding to other responses, although I use the Puma multi-threaded server.

What is the correct way to implement functionality like this?

Comment: I get same issue, plz help if you have solution of above issue, thanks in advance

Comment: I think now that probably ruby on rails is not best option here. Have you tried toimplement that part using node.js?

Answer (score 0):

**I get the solution**

```
  puts "."
  client.add_message_callback do |message|
    if message.type != :error
        arr = message.from.to_s.split('@')
        puts arr[0]
        puts message.body 

    end
  end

 while 1
 end
```